# php if array key exists inside multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

how can i check if logo exists in this array called $attachements print_r is below:

> Array (
>       [logo] => /home/richar2/public_html/ioagh/images/stories/jreviews/20100510115659_1_img.gif
>   )

when theres no logo, the array print_r's

> Array ( )

i tried:
if (isset($attachments['logo']) ) {..}
but the conditional code runs when there is no logo

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `array_key_exists`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

It's very stange that isset() is not working, I am pretty sure it should. Maybe you have a problem elsewhere in your code.

Anyway, if you want to try something else, there is a specific function: [array_key_exists()](http://it.php.net/array_key_exists)

Comment: From example #2 on the PHP array_key_exists page:

"isset() does not return TRUE for array keys that correspond to a NULL value, while array_key_exists() does."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

This works for me as expected:

```
$arr['logo'] = '/home/richar2/public_html/ioagh/images/stories/jreviews/20100510115659_1_img.gif';
print_r($arr);

if (isset($arr['logo'])){
    echo $arr['logo'];
}else{
    echo 'Key doesn\'t exist!';
}
```

Are you sure you set $arr['logo'] = null, not $arr['logo'] = ''?
For the latter you can also check

```
if (isset($arr['logo'] && !empty($arr['logo'])){
...
}
```

Comment: If that's the case ($arr['logo'] = ''), you should use empty() to check if $arr['logo'] is set to a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

> but the conditional code runs when
>   there is no logo

You could construct an `else` clause to take appropriate action:

```
if (isset($attachments['logo']))
{
  // logo is set
}
else
{
  // loto is not set
}
```

Or simply try this:

```
if (array_key_exists('logo', $attachments))
{
    // logo is set
}
```

More info on **[`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Answer (score 0):

you could write it like:

```
function md_array_key_exists ($key, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $item => $val)
    {
        if ($item === $key)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (is_array ($val))
        {
            if (true == marray_key_exists ($key, $val))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```